# Unable to run org.h2.tools.Script from command line in AUTOSERVER mode

Tags: h2, apache-tomee

I am running H2 in auto-server mode, so that multiple processes can access it. But  I am unable to run org.h2.tools.Script from command line when TOMEE is already using it. If I shut down TOMEE , org.h2.tools.Script works fine.

**Here is the command I am using:**
`java -cp h2-1.4.188.jar org.h2.tools.Script -url 'jdbc:h2:~/test;FILE_LOCK=FILE;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE' -user sa -password sa -script test.sql`

**Exception I get when I issue the command when Tomcat is up**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/test.sql (Permission denied)"; SQL statement:
SCRIPT  TO '/var/lib/test.sql'  [90028-188]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:345)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:168)
        at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:328)
        at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openOutput(ScriptBase.java:146)
        at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptCommand.query(ScriptCommand.java:159)
        at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.query(CommandContainer.java:90)
        at org.h2.command.Command.executeQuery(Command.java:197)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:320)
        at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:159)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/test.sql (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:101)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newOutputStream(FilePathDisk.java:290)
        at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newOutputStream(FileUtils.java:233)
        at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openOutput(ScriptBase.java:144)
        ... 6 more

        at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.done(SessionRemote.java:624)
        at org.h2.command.CommandRemote.executeQuery(CommandRemote.java:158)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:179)
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:158)
        at org.h2.tools.Script.process(Script.java:141)
        at org.h2.tools.Script.process(Script.java:120)
        at org.h2.tools.Script.runTool(Script.java:101)
        at org.h2.tools.Script.main(Script.java:46)
```

I am not sure why I see `FileNotFoundException`. Remember this goes away when TOMEE isn't running.

Any ideas ? I am in a docker container. I made sure that URL matches between TOMEE and Script.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this is happening. TOMEE process is running as 'test' user while the Script command is running as root. Since TOMEE, gets to access H2 DB first,  'test' user should have permissions to write to /var/lib/.  But /var/lib folder has permissions for root user, so test user can't write to it.